# how to display dynamic column names in UI using p:columns tag?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using Hibernate and jsf with primefaces.I got list of data and it is displayed on console. but i am unable to display data throgh UI using `<p:columns>` Tag. My Xhtml page having one drop-down box and check-box. My datacolumn should be display based on check-box. If checkbox value is true then display all columns otherwise should be display selected columns dynamically.

XHTML Page:

```
 <p:dataTable id="tbl" var="dept" rendered="#{deptBean.visible}"
             value="#{deptBean.getDepusers1()}"
             scrollRows="20" scrollable="false" liveScroll="false"
             scrollHeight="340" mode="inline" 
             styleClass="report-table"
             rowClasses="report-table-odd-row, report-table-even-row">


    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Save&nbsp;as&nbsp;&nbsp;" class="reportSubHeadingFont"/>
        <h:commandLink>
            <p:graphicImage value="resources/images/csv.png" />
            <p:dataExporter type="csv" target="tbl" fileName="Department_Users" />
        </h:commandLink>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <h:commandLink>
            <p:graphicImage value="resources/images/excel.png" />
            <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="tbl" fileName="Department_Users" />
        </h:commandLink>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <h:commandLink>
            <p:graphicImage value="resources/images/xml.png" />
            <p:dataExporter type="xml" target="tbl" fileName="Department_Users" />
        </h:commandLink>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <h:commandLink>
            <p:graphicImage value="resources/images/pdf.png" />
            <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="tbl" fileName="Department_Users" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </f:facet>

    <p:columns value="#{deptBean.dataTableColumns}" var="column"   columnIndexVar="colIndex" sortBy="#{dept[column.property]}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{column.header}" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{dept[column.property]}" />                      
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

Bean Class:

```
    public List executeQuery() {

        try
        {
        dataTableColumns = new ArrayList<DataTableColumn>();

        setVisible(true);
        log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
        System.out.println("selectedcheckbox" + checkboxvalue);
        System.out.println("selectd dep user " + selectddep_user);
        int deptID = Integer.parseInt(selectddep_user);
        DepartmentDao dedao=new DepartmentDao();
        HttpSession httpsession= Util.getSession();
        String role= (String)httpsession.getAttribute("role");

        if (checkboxvalue.equals("true")) {

            depusersDetailGrid = new UserDAO().getUsersWithDetailsByDeptId(deptID);
            System.out.println("depusersDetailGrid generated");


            for (DepartmentUsersDetailedGrid ss : depusersDetailGrid) {
                System.out.println(ss.getFirstName());
                System.out.println(ss.getLoginId());
                System.out.println(ss.getEmail());
                System.out.println(ss.getMobileNo());
                System.out.println(ss.getRoleId());
            }

        } else {

            depusersGrid = new UserDAO().getAllUsers_Department();

            for (DepartmentUsersGrid ad : depusersGrid) {
                System.out.println(ad.getDeptName());
                System.out.println(ad.getNoOfUsers());
            }

        }

        depusers1.add(depusersDetailGrid);
        depusers1.add(depusersGrid);

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error("Exception occured in ",e);

        }
        return depusers1;
    }


}
```

Comment: i already tried.In primefaces showcase the column names are hard coded in array list.But i need to get coulmn names in dymanically and diplayed with data.

Comment: that way also tried but only column names displayed not displaying data.please provide any solution

Comment: Bad idea to use column word for var expression. Because column it's reserved word and this can lead to errors work compoment.